# ¿Cual puede ser el error en este problema de herencia?

Tags: java, poo, herencia

Necesito crear un aula donde mi clase padre es persona y mis clases hijas son alumnos, alumno extranjero y profesor. todas las nuevas personas las agrego a un arraylist dependiendo del tipo de persona que sean.
Para poder crear la clase necesito minimo un profesor y 5 alumnos. Para verificar eso utilizo este public void en una clase:

```
public boolean condiciones() {
    if(profesor.size() < 1 && (alumno.size()+ alumnoextranjero.size()) < 5){
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
```

y para verificar en el main agrego lo siguiente (condiciones2 es solo un public void donde me imprime las condiciones necesarias y que me falta para poder terminar el programa):

```
while(proceso==1) {
        a1.agregarpersona();
        System.out.println("¿Desea agregar a otra persona? 1.Si||0.No");
        desicion = datos.nextInt();
        if(desicion==0) {
            if(a1.condiciones()==false){
                a1.condiciones2();
            }else {
                proceso = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
```

El problema es que no importa cuantos alumnos agregue, si agrego un solo profesor y elijo ya no agregar a otra persona imprime todo y termina el programa. ¿cual puede ser el error?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te está pasando es que cuando evalúas el IF al no cumplirse esta expresión `profesor.size() < 1` ya pasa automáticamente al else prueba enfocando la condición al revés

```
if(profesor.size() > 0 && (alumno.size()+ alumnoextranjero.size()) > 4){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

La condición para evaluar que al menos tenga 1 profesor y 5 alumnos tu la tienes así :

```
if(profesor.size() < 1 && (alumno.size()+ alumnoextranjero.size()) < 5)
```

Y sería de está forma :

```
if(profesor.size() >= 1 && (alumno.size()+ alumnoextranjero.size()) >=5)
```

Comment: Creo que se te ha ido un `no` en la segunda oracion.